# Buttons not working inside $timout/ setTimeout | Angular and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, scope

I've want to display a popup, but with a bit of delay. The problem is that when I'm not delaying the popup the buttons aren't working and when I'm adding the delay the buttons don't show up! I've read online that the $timeout is an async function, but that isn't the issue, or is it?

The popup:

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    templateUrl: 'templates/components/welcomePopup.html',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Hejdå!',
        type: 'custom-save-button',
        onTap: function (e) {
            $scope.showSpinner = true

        }
    }]
})
```

How I delay it:

```
$timeout(function (){
// Popup here
}, 3000)
```

But when adding a delay my buttons aren’t showing and without they delay nothing is working.

```
buttons: [{
  text: 'Hejdå!',
  type: 'custom-save-button',
```

Does anyone know a quick fix?

This is the code at the moment:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        templateUrl: 'templates/components/welcomePopup.html',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Hejdå!',
            type: 'custom-save-button',
            onTap: function (e) {
                $scope.showSpinner = true

            }
        }]
    })
}, 3000)
```

Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve half of the problem. I suspected that the problem had something to do with the `$scope` and apparently I was correct.

So I added another `$scope` to:

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    templateUrl: 'templates/components/welcomePopup.html',
    scope: $scope.$scope, // added $scope
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Hejdå!',
        type: 'custom-save-button',
        onTap: function (e) {
            $scope.showSpinner = true

        }
    }]
})
```

However, the buttons aren't working yet!

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not working because when you do something on your `$scope` in the timeout context, you're not anymore in your controller context.

The variable `showSpinner` should be actually set to `true` when you tap on the button, the problem is that Angular isn't aware that the value has changed, and therefore does not refresh the view.

To solve this, you can force a refresh by adding that piece of code after you change the value in your scope:

```
if ($scope.$root.$$phase !== '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase !== '$digest') {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

The condition is to prevent a refresh request while there is already one in progress.
Therefore, I don't think you need to pass a $scope inside your main $scope.

Hope this helps!